# How to pass two textboxes values to a function in Angular6?

Tags: angular

I'm from AngularJs background.
I've a code like below:

```
Username:<input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
 <br>
Password:<input type="text" ng-model="user.password">
 <br>
<input type="button" value="Login" ng-click="funlogin(user)">
```

this will works in AngularJs.

But, I want to do same thing in Angular. Is it possible?. I've wrote Angular Code like below:

```
Username:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.username">
 <br>
Password:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
 <br>
<input type="button" value="Login" (click)="funlogin(user)">
```

But, It's not working.

> ERROR: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined.

Comment: i don't understand the problem are the values not getting updated from the Model?

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: can you show , how and where your object is define

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a property/variable into component.ts like this

```
public user : any = {};
```

**Edit:** Here is your component will look like

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      public user: any = {};

      constructor() {

      }
      ngOnInit(): void {

      }
    }
```

Comment: But, The error is coming at HTML and not even going to TS.

Comment: But you have to add this line into component.ts

Comment: Can you please post sample compnent.ts file like what u are saying. Because i don't know even how to create it?

Answer (score 1):

Declare this variable inside the component

```
 public user: any = {};
```

And change the template as below

```
Username:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.username">
 <br>
Password:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
 <br>
<input type="button" value="Login" (click)="funlogin()">
```

No need to pass 'user' inside the function since the angular two way data binding updates the 'user' inside your component when the template is changing

You can directly access it in your function

```
funlogin() {

  // this.user

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it works in Angular2+ is.. whatever property you are using in your templates for the binding purpose.. should be a public property in your component. Since in your template you are using **user** object (**'user.username'**) you will need to have user object inside your component:

Define a public property in your component like this:

```
public user = { username: '', password: '' };
```

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed like this:

```
class cls1{

public user:any={}
t1;t2:string;
funlogin(user){
    if(user.username=="scott" && user.password =="scott123")
    {
      alert("Valid")
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Invalid")
    }
   }
 }
```

Thanks to [@Ali Shahbaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203961/ali-shahbaz)